# Catch all routes not working after update Asp.Net WebApi 5.2.2 to 5.2.7

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Consider the following route

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "myApi",
    baseRoute + "myApi/file/{param1}/{*param2}",
    new {controller = "File"}
);
```

This catch-all route triggers the FileController

```
[HttpGet]
public object Get(string param1, string param2)
{
    //...
}
```

With WebApi 5.2.2 the controller is triggered with urls

- http://www.something/myApi/a/b
- http://www.something/myApi/a/b/c/d/e

The second case results in param2 = "b/c/d/e" which is how this catch-all route works (at least for version 5.2.2).

The problem now is that for version 5.2.7 the second case does not work any more. I could not see anything relevant in the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-22). Does anybody have an idea what is the problem?

**EDIT**

I generalized the problem to much in my question. I have a problem with

- http://www.something/myApi/a/b/c/d/e.f

The dot character is causing a problem it seems.

Comment: I cn already tell you, it's also working for 5.2.4. I'm now also updating to 5.2.7. I'll let you know the results.

Comment: Still seems to be working. I created a small lab project, added a route `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("CatchAllApi", "api/{controller}/{id}/{*rest}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });`. Controller has `public string Get(int id, string rest)` and rest is filled correctly with `a/b/c`, when I call `/api/values/5/a/b/c`. Seems to be an issue in some other part. I updated ALL NuGet packages to the newest version. Maybe there is a mismatch in your packages?

Comment: Please let me know the versions of all relevant libraries (Microsoft.AspNet.*) should be enough. Then, I'll try to reproduce again.

Comment: @ChristophHerold Thanks for your investigation. See my edit and my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutuion in my case was the following. I had to add an addtional extenstionless url handler.

So additionally to

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0_1a" path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

I needed

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0_1a" path="*.*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Comment: Interesting, in a freshly created project, it even looks like a mix of your two entries: `<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />`. So, path is neither `*` nor `*.*`, but `*.`. Maybe that is the clean solution?

Comment: Very strange. What happens when YOU create a completely new solution in VS? What does your web.config look like? I don't even have the `_1a` suffix in the name.